# memory limit in com+

Tags: memory-management, com+

We have a couple of win 2000 boxes with com+ and we're occasionally getting "insufficient memory to perform that operation" errors with the dtsearch.dtengine dll.  Since it's registered in com+ I was hoping there was a way to limit the amount of memory it used and then recycle it once it hits that but I can't seem to find a way to do that.  Anyone know how?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To configure application recycling for a COM+ application, use the following steps:

In the console tree of the Component Services administrative tool, right-click the COM+ server application you want to be recycled and then click Properties.

On the Pooling & Recycling tab, enter values for Lifetime Limit (minutes), Memory Limit (KB), Expiration Timeout (minutes), Call Limit, and Activation Limit, depending on the criteria you want to use.

Lifetime Limit indicates the maximum number of minutes a process can run before it's recycled. The valid range is 0 through 30,240 minutes (21 days). The default number of minutes is 0.

Memory Limit indicates the maximum amount of process memory usage (in kilobytes) before recycling the process. If the process's memory usage exceeds the specified number for longer than one minute, the process is recycled. The valid range is 0 through 1,048,576 KB, and the default amount of memory usage is 0 KB.

Expiration Timeout indicates the number of minutes to wait, before being forcibly shut down, for the release of all external references to objects in the process. The valid range is 1 through 1440 minutes (24 hours), and the default expiration time-out is 15 minutes. This value is used only when it is already determined that a process will be recycled based on the other criteria.

Call Limit indicates the maximum number of calls that application objects can accept before recycling the process. The valid range is 0 through 1,048,576 calls, and the default number of calls is 0.

Activation Limit indicates the maximum number of application object activations to accept before recycling the process. The valid range is 0 through 1,048,576 activations, and the default number of activations is 0.

Note   When the Lifetime Limit, Memory Limit, Call Limit, or Activation Limit value is set to 0 (the default value), application recycling for that criterion is disabled. When all four of these criteria are set to 0, application recycling is disabled for the selected application.